# Terminal does not accept root password (just changed it)

Tags: macos, root

Using `dsenableroot` I've just changed the password to a very simple one and terminal says

`***Successfully enabled root user.`

Then I run a command with sudo and it won't accept the password I just set. 
Tried setting different passwords and opening new terminals but it doesn't help.

What can be the problem and how do I even debug this?

Comment: Doesn't sudo take the current user's password by default? In order to do it as the root user you have to first **be** the root user.

Comment: sudo certainly doesn't need root enabled. Almost nothing on a mac requires root to be enabled… which is why it isn't by default. Best guess right now, root is not even in the sudoers list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the password of the current user (who needs to be in the `admin` group unless you changed `sudoers`) if you run `sudo`.

PS: as other people already mentioned in the comments: you don‘t need to enable `root` to run `sudo`, basically you don‘t need to enable it at all.